# How to scale the texture used by Displace modifier

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to create a displacement texture. However the texture is appearing too small on object.

How do I fix this? I began by subdividing the plane multiple times and then added displacement texture.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using "repeat" mapping, with crop maximum x/y values of 10. Is it better if you set both to 1?

Comment: You'll make it easier for those who might wish to help you if you post a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend-Echange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), and edit a link to the file into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Displacement map made with procedural textures**

Switch to **Textures** panel in order to open texture used by **Displace** modifier. You will find different options which vary depending on texture type. The *Size* option is accessible for many of them which is one you need if you work with procedural textures.

[image: procedural displacement map settings]

**Image textures**

If you have image texture, I'd suggest changing texture coordinates which use **Displace** modifier.

1. In modifier's panel, *Texture Coordinates* option, change it to *Object*.
2. Add a simple plane somewhere nearby, choose it as object in mentioned option.
3. Now to scale image which is used as displacement map scale that added mesh. Displacement map will be resized according to that:

[image: image texture displacement map sizing]

Comment: Instead of a Plane, you can also use an "Empty"

Answer (score 1):

Under the 'Image Mapping' tab, change the crop maximum to:
X: 1.00
Y: 1.00

Comment: I have just tied that it didnt make it bigger